# $Var(\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\beta}_{F G L S}-\beta\right))=s^2_{FGLS}(\frac{1}{N} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \hat{\Omega}^{-1} \mathbf{X})^{-1}$?

Tags: variance, generalized-least-squares

If so, Wikipedia is wrong?

Wikipedia:

> $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\beta}_{F G L S}-\beta\right) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0, \mathrm{p}-\lim \left(X^{\prime} \Omega^{-1} X / T\right))$

Powerll from University of California, Berkley:

> $\sqrt{N}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{F G L S}-\boldsymbol{\beta}\right) \stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} N(\mathbf{0}, \operatorname{plim} s_{F G L S}^2\left(\frac{1}{N} \mathbf{X}^{\prime} \hat{\Omega}^{-1} \mathbf{X}\right)^{-1})$

Aside, I am not sure what $s^2_{FGLS}$ is.

[https://eml.berkeley.edu/~powell/e240b_sp06/glsnotes.pdf](https://eml.berkeley.edu/%7Epowell/e240b_sp06/glsnotes.pdf)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares

Convention equivalences

$T=N$

$\sqrt{N}=\sqrt{n}$

---

https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/593699/edit

> 

$A = S D S^{-1}$,

then

$A^{-1} = (SDS^{-1})^{-1} = (S^{-1})^{-1} D^{-1} S^{-1} = S D^{-1} S^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi: wikipedia probably assumes that the individual elements of $\Omega$  have the $s^2_{FGLS}$ multiplying them already, whereas Powell doesn't. Other than that, are there any other differences that are there between the two that i'm missing.

Comment: What about the extra inverse in Powell? @mlofton

Comment: Oops, I missed that. According to User1865345, Powell is correct and his explanation ( although I didn't read it carefully ), definitely lends credibility to that. Great Answer. Someday, when I have more time, I'll read it and try to follow it. A nice intro textbook that I found recently that probably has relevant material is "An Introduction To Econometric Theory" by Davidson. It doesn't get deep like Schmidt or Davidson's other texts but it still looks good at a quick glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the outset, one of the confusions emanates from the two usage to state violation of homoscedasticity: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares#Method_outline) follows $\operatorname{Cov}[\boldsymbol\varepsilon|\mathbf X] =\mathbf \Omega$ whereas many authors do prefer $\mathbb E\left[\boldsymbol\varepsilon\boldsymbol\varepsilon  ^\mathsf T |\mathbf X\right]=\sigma^2\mathbf\Omega.$

Few lines worth to spend:

If $\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}$ is the GLS estimator of the parameters, then its covariance matrix is $\sigma^2\left(\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X\right) ^{-1}.$ Then its asymptotic covariance matrix is $$\frac{\sigma^2}T\lim_{T\to\infty}\left(\frac{\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X}T\right) ^{-1}.\tag 1$$ Also an unbiased, consistent, efficient as well as asymptotically efficient estimator of $\sigma^2$ is $$\tilde\sigma^2:=\frac{\tilde{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}^\mathsf T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\tilde{\boldsymbol\varepsilon}}{T-K}.\tag 2$$ This is what Powell meant by $s^2_{\text{GLS}}.$ That is,

$$\operatorname{plim} s^2_{\text{GLS}} =\sigma^2.\tag{2.I}$$

Now, $$\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}\sim\mathcal N\left(\boldsymbol\beta,\sigma^2\left(\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X\right) ^{-1}\right).\tag 3$$

Then,  as Powell showed,

$$ \sqrt T\left(\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)\overset{\mathcal L}{\to}\mathcal N\left(\boldsymbol 0,\operatorname{plim}s^2_{\text{GLS}}\left(\frac{\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X}{T}\right) ^{-1}\right).\tag 4$$

In the same vein, when $\mathbf\Omega$ is not known, then its estimator $\hat{\mathbf \Omega}$ is used in place of $\mathbf \Omega$ and this is the essence of feasible GLS. Let the corresponding estimator be $\bar{\bar {\boldsymbol \beta}}.$

Now, \begin{align}\operatorname{plim}\sqrt T\left(\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)&=\operatorname{plim}\left(\underbrace{\frac{\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X}T}_{\mathsf A2}\right) ^{-1}\operatorname{plim}\underbrace{\frac{\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\boldsymbol\varepsilon}{\sqrt T}}_{\mathsf B2},\tag{5.I}\\\operatorname{plim}\sqrt T\left(\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol\beta}}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)&=\operatorname{plim}\left(\underbrace{\frac{\mathbf X^\mathsf T\hat{\mathbf \Omega}^{-1}\mathbf X}T}_{\mathsf A1}\right) ^{-1}\operatorname{plim}\underbrace{\frac{\mathbf X^\mathsf T\hat{\mathbf \Omega}^{-1}\boldsymbol\varepsilon}{\sqrt T}}_{\mathsf B1};\tag{5.II}\end{align}

$\operatorname{plim}\mathsf{A2}= \operatorname{plim}\mathsf{A1}$ and $\operatorname{plim}\mathsf{B2}= \operatorname{plim}\mathsf{B1}$ ensure that (in fact, sufficient) FGLS estimator and GLS estimator have the same asymptotic distribution whence $\sqrt T\left(\tilde{\boldsymbol\beta}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)$ and $\sqrt T\left(\bar{\bar{\boldsymbol\beta}}-\boldsymbol\beta\right)$ have the same asymptotic distribution $\mathcal N\left(\boldsymbol 0,\sigma^2\mathbf Q^{-1}\right)$ where $\mathbf Q:= \operatorname{plim}\left(\frac{\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf \Omega^{-1}\mathbf X}{T}\right) . $

So, Powell is correct. He used $\operatorname{plim} s^2_{\text{FGLM}} =\sigma^2.$

---

### References:

$[1]$ Econometrics, *Peter Schmidt*, Taylor & Francis Group, $1976.$

$[2]$ Econometrics, *Badi H. Baltagi*, Springer-Verlag, $2008.$

Comment: Till this [edit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MobileDiff/603353292), Wikipedia had the inverse. It used both $T$ and $n.$

Comment: Is Wikipedia wrong?

Comment: It seems so. In general also, it's not apt to follow Wikipedia blindly. You have Powell and other good books to follow.